# How can i find target for command WaitTextForPresent in selenium ide in an ajax website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium, selenium-ide

I am new on java script, selenium IDE and web developing. Right now, i am currently studying web http://chat-id.com/ that use ajax application. I want to use command WaitTextForPresent to detect a unique chat message has appeared but i dont know where to target the command. anyone can help?

[update]

```
    <div id="logbox" class="logbox">
        -many other <div id= >
        <div class="logitem"></div>
        <div class="logitem">
            <div class="strangermsg">
                <span class="msgsource"> Teman Kamu: </span>

                F

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've Tried many thing such as: AssertForElement, AssertVisble, etc. but doesnt have any good result. my main problem is how to find exact target for those commands.

The best command i've tried so far is

```
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>css=div.strangermsg</td>
    <td>F</td>
</tr>
```

And The Result:

> [error] Actual value 'Teman Kamu: F?' did not match 'F'

it's almost get it. But i want only its text message= 'F' without *span class* 'Teman Kamu: ' (Teman kamu means Stranger in English

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the question..^^
I've Tried many thing such as: AssertForElement, AssertVisble, etc. but doesnt have any good result. my main problem is how to find exact target for those commands.

The best command i've tried so far is
<tr>
 <td>assertText</td>
 <td>css=div.strangermsg</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

And The Result:
[error] Actual value 'Teman Kamu: F?' did not match ''
it's almost get it. But what i want is only its text message= 'F?' without <span> 'Teman Kamu'</span> (Teman kamu means Stranger in English

Comment: Sounds like you need string manipulation. But without additional info we are only going to be guessing. To help us help you, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yup, i think it's string manipulation. Thanks for ur suggestion. i will try to update the question

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this, if you use junit test.

```
WebElement message;
  for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
     message = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='logbox']/div[" + i + "]/logitem")));
```

I haven't find another solution for wait next message by using a different thing than the `for()`

Comment: OP said he is using Selenium IDE and JavaScript.

Comment: but thanks, somehow i get a little bit information about its target.. :)